# GPIO Expander with isolation

Tags: microcontroller, analog, gpio, expander

Is there any GPIO expander with galvanic isolation? I browsed a lot and couldnt find any GPIO expander with isolation.Thanks in advacne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MCP23017(similar to MCP23S17 but not SPI) which is I2C based IOExpander. You need to isolate only 2 lines with a bidirectional isolator. For that you may use ADuM1251.

Comment: I particularly chose SPI because all its lines are unidirectional and therefore much easier to isolate. The ADuM1251 is much more expensive than a quad optocoupler, so only having 2 lines doesn't gain you anything.

Comment: user790572 does not have much pins as commented on your answer so he may not have as many slave select pins at his disposal. In case of I2C based IOExp the addressing is done in software where last three bits are set by the address lines on the IC. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You can also use ADum1250 with one bidirectional Isolation as we do not need bidirectional isolation for SCK line.

Comment: Many people don't seem to know this, but the I2C clock line is actually bidirectional. The slave can [stretch](http://www.i2c-bus.org/clock-stretching/) it to control bus speed.

Comment: Ok! here is my very basic doubt. If I have an IO Expander, dont  I need to isolate every output it provides if it doesnt comes with isolation(galvanic or opto)?? Or is it like the isolation as mentioned such as ADuM1251 is suffice?

Comment: ADum1251 or any other opto with IOExp will only isolate your controller from the I/Os. The idea is to isolate N number of I/O lines by isolating only 2 lines.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the usual shift register like the [74HC595](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf), and use optocouplers for passing the data, clock, and latch signals. The [LVT-847](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTV-817_827_847%28M,S,S_TA1%29.pdf) is a quad optocoupler which costs less than a dollar in 1s at Digikey. Note that its speed is limited to less than 100 kHz.

**edit**
You comment that you want to read output status as well. The [MCP23S17](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21952a.pdf) is a 16-bit I/O expander with SPI interface. SPI needs 4 wires: SCK, MOSI, MISO, and SS, so that the quad optocoupler still will work. If you need more I/O you can hook up extra MCP23S17s to the same SPI bus, but you'll need a separate SS line for each expander. Just add optocouplers to each of the pins coming from/going to the microcontroller (SPI master).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason for using GPIO expander is my microcontroller doesnt ve that much of pins, and on top of it, I am looking for some IC with galvanic or opto isolation, for reducing the size of the board, and I want to read the status of the outputs @ times.

Comment: @user790572 (don't you have a name?) - I updated my answer.